# optimization recomendations for displaying SVG overlays with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I am aiming to display custom region border overlays with complex visual styling and svg seems the ideal choice. But just in doing some initial feasibility testing I am running into extreme performance issues when I have around 20 added to the map using the `GroundOverlay` class. My desktop with decent gpu is brought to its knees in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge when panning or zooming or sometimes even when just idle with a static map view onscreen, with cpu & gpu usage spiking and, in Firefox's case, even maxing out my 16 gigs of ram (ff memory leak??). Since SO doesn't allow svg attaching here is the source of an example svg I'm using (it's the borders of California with a semi-transparent gradient fill):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="959" height="593">
<title>California</title>
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:white;
      stop-opacity:0" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
  <style type="text/css">
    .state {fill:url(#grad1);}
  </style>
</defs>
<g id="outlines" class="state">  
  <path id="CA" d="M122.7 385.9l-19.7-2.7-10-1.5-.5-1.8v-9.4l-.3-3.2-2.6-4.2-.8-2.3-3.9-4.2-2.9-4.7-2.7-.2-3.2-.8-.3-1 1.5-.6-.6-3.2-1.5-2.1-4.8-.8-3.9-2.1-1.1-2.3-2.6-4.8-2.9-3.1H57l-3.9-2.1-4.5-1.8-4.2-.5-2.4-2.7.5-1.9 1.8-7.1.8-1.9v-2.4l-1.6-1-.5-2.9-1.5-2.6-3.4-5.8-1.3-3.1-1.5-4.7-1.6-5.3-3.2-4.4-.5-2.9.8-3.9h1.1l2.1-1.6 1.1-3.6-1-2.7-2.7-.5-1.9-2.6-2.1-3.7-.2-8.2.6-1.9.6-2.3.5-2.4-5.7-6.3V236l.3-.5.3-3.2-1.3-4-2.3-4.8-2.7-4.5-1.8-3.9 1-3.7.6-5.8 1.8-3.1.3-6.5-1.1-3.6-1.6-4.2L14 184l.8-3.2 1.5-4.2 1.8-.8.3-1.1 3.1-2.6 5.2-11.8.2-7.4 1.69-4.9 38.69 11.8 25.6 6.6-8 31.3-8.67 33.1L88.84 250 131 312.3l17.1 26.1-.4 3.1 2.8 5.2 1.1 5.4 1 1.5.7.6-.2 1.4-1.4 1-3.4 1.6-1.9 2.1-1.7 3.9-.5 4.7-2.6 2.5-2.3 1.1-.1 6.2-.6 1.9 1 1.7 3 .3-.4 1.6-1.4 2-3.9.6zM48.8 337l1.3 1.5-.2 1.3-3.2-.1-.6-1.2-.6-1.5zm1.9 0l1.2-.6 3.6 2.1 3.1 1.2-.9.6-4.5-.2-1.6-1.6zm20.7 19.8l1.8 2.3.8 1 1.5.6.6-1.5-1-1.8-2.7-2-1.1.2v1.2zm-1.4 8.7l1.8 3.2 1.2 1.9-1.5.2-1.3-1.2s-.7-1.5-.7-1.9v-2.2z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm displaying it and about 20 similar in an otherwise empty custom map using

```js
svgoverlay1 = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(myurl, mybounds, {clickable: false}));
svgoverlay1.setMap(map);
```

Just wondering if anyone out there has experience performance tuning the display of multiple svgs like this over a map. Is there an alternative approach to `GroundOverlay` that would be more performant and better suited for this? Is there some way my svg itself could be better optimized for this purpose? I was thinking that as far as svgs go this was was following best practices for optimization (no giant floats as path points, limited number of total points, etc.).

Comment: Create Polygons.

Comment: Polygons are way less expensive to display, yes, but very limited in appearance styling options. Can't do anything fancy with gradients and partial transparencies as in my svg example.

Comment: Yes, so maybe that's where you need to make a choice. Performance vs fancy visuals... Performance with Polygons will also depend on the complexity of your shapes; the more complex, the slower they'll be rendered.

Comment: The thing is, I've found that polygons with 100+ points still render way faster than svgs with only tens of points. There's something really inefficient about the way svgs are being handled.